# Using fwrite() to write structure within queue structure into binary file

Tags: c, data-structures, file-handling, fwrite

I want to write a struct from queue (data structure) struct using fwrite() into a binary file.

```
struct addressbook
{
    char first[15];
    char surname[15];
    char address[60];
    char city[15];
    char country[15];
    char zip[6];
    char phone[15];
    char mob[15];
};

struct node
{
    struct addressbook data;
    struct node *next;
};

struct node *front = NULL;
struct node *rear = NULL;
```

My code is as follows:

```
void writedata (void)
{
    FILE *fp;

    char CONTINUE;

    struct addressbook blank;
    struct node *temp;

    fp = fopen("asdf.dat","ab");

    while(1)
    {
        temp = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));

        if (temp != NULL)
        {
            fflush(stdin);
            printf("\nEnter First name?\n");
            gets(temp->data.first);

            printf("Enter Surname?\n");
            gets(temp->data.surname);

            printf("Enter Street Address (with commas)?\n");
            gets(temp->data.address);

            printf("Enter City?\n");
            gets(temp->data.city);

            printf("Enter Country?\n");
            gets(temp->data.country);

            printf("Enter Zipcode?\n");
            gets(temp->data.zip);

            printf("Enter Phone number?\n");
            gets(temp->data.phone);

            printf("Enter Mobile number?\n");
            gets(temp->data.mob);

            temp->next = NULL;

            fwrite(&temp->data,sizeof(struct addressbook),1,fp);

            if (front == NULL)
            {
                front = temp;
            }

            else
            {
                rear->next = temp;
            }

            rear = temp;

        }

        else
        {
            printf( "No memory available.\n");
        }

        printf("CONTINUE\nY-YES \nN-NO\n? ");
        fflush(stdin);
        CONTINUE = getchar();

        if (CONTINUE == 'N' || CONTINUE == 'n')
            break;
    }

    fclose(fp);
}
```

I am getting garbage value at the output.

Comment: See [Why the `gets()` function is too dangerous to be used — ever!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-dangerous-why-should-it-not-be-used) and then repent of your previous ignorance (revise the code to use `fgets()` or a similar function).  Also note the caveats about [Using `fflush(stdin)`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979209/using-fflushstdin).

Comment: You should probably identify what your input is, and the garbage output you get — possibly as a hex dump of the file.  You need only show one record.  Note that one of the problems with using `gets()` is that you're relying on the user not to enter too much data.  You might want to think about reading each value into a big buffer (`char buffer[4096];` for example), and then checking whether what was typed will fit.  You should also check each input call to ensure it did not fail.  EOF can occur at any time.  Please read about how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]), though you're pretty close here.

Comment: "I am getting garbage value at the output" - the only output from this code are the prompts to the user for *input*. What output are you referring to, the target file content? Are you expecting something *other* than a block of data, some of which is the input data, the rest being the indeterminate content of the unspecified data in each field? That's all you're going to get. If you have a 15 char indeterminate buffer, populate ten chars with a nine-char string + nullchar, you're going to get exactly what you wrote: 10 chars of determinate data, and five more of indeterminate content.

Comment: the posted code does not compile!  At the very least, it is missing the `main()` function and the statement: `#include <stdio.h>`

Comment: While visual studio will allow you to use: `fflush(stdin)`  The function: `fflush()` is for output streams, no input streams.  Suggest using: `int ch;  while( (ch = getchar()) != EOF && '\n' != ch );`

Comment: the posted code contains several 'magic' numbers.  'magic' numbers are numbers with no basis. I.E. 5, 15, 60.  'magic' numbers make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  Suggest use a `enum` statement or `#define` statements to give those 'magic' numbers meaningful names, then use those meaningful names throughout the code.

Comment: in function: `writedata()`, the variable `CONTINUE` is the same spelling as the `continue` loop iterator. It is poor program practice to have variable names that are the same as the C operators.  Having the same name with the only difference being the capitalization  is very confusing to the human reader of the code.  Note: it is typical for ALL_CAPS to be used for `#define` and `enum` names.  Using variable names that are all caps is confusing to the human reader.

Comment: when calling `fopen()`, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  If NULL, then call `perror()` then `exit()`  The `perror()` will display (on stderr) the text you supplied plus the reason the system thinks the function failed.

Comment: when calling any of the heap allocation functions: (malloc, calloc, realloc), 1) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  2) the return value type is `void*` which can be assigned to any other pointer.  Casting the returned value just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, etc.

Comment: error messages should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout`, so this line: `printf( "No memory available.\n");` should be: `perror( "malloc failed" );`

Comment: this line: `fwrite(&temp->data,sizeof(struct addressbook),1,fp);
` should be followed by a check of the returned value from`fwrite()`, AND that would be a good time to pass the pointer returned from `malloc()` to `free()`  OR better, reuse the same memory space, then pass to `free()` before exiting the program.

Comment: you could simplify the statement: `if (CONTINUE == 'N' || CONTINUE == 'n')`  by replacing it with: `if( 'N' == toupper( CONTINUE ) )`  Note: `toupper()` is available by the statement: `#include <ctype.h>`

Comment: when the call to `malloc()` fails, it will continue to fail.  so when it fails, cleanup (close open files, free allocated memory, etc) then call `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`  where `exit()` and `EXIT_FAILURE` are available by the statement: `#include <stdlib.h>`

Comment: Did you notice that the variable named `blank` is not used, so should be eliminated

Comment: in the latest version of the C programming language, the function: `gets()` is completely removed.  (previously, it was just depreciated).   Strongly suggest using `fgets()`  to input the values,  Note: `fgets()` will include the trailing newline '\n' so that needs to be removed via something similar to: `char *newline = NULL;  if( NULL != (newline = strchr( <which ever input buffer>, '\n' ) ) { *newline = '\0'' }`

Comment: just to give you an example, this line: `gets(temp->data.first); should be: `if( !fgets( temp->data.first, sizeof( struct addressbook.first), stdin ) ) { perror( "fgets for first name failed" ); .... }`  Note: if meaningful names are used for the size of each field then replace: `sizeof( struct addressbook.first)` with that meaningful name

Comment: to avoid having garbage in the data written to the file, after calling `malloc()` and before setting any fields, insert the statement: `memset( temp, '\0', sizeof( struct node) )`

Comment: to avoid confusing the user, in the prompts for `Phone number` and `Mobile number`, include the expected format in the prompt.  something similar to `(###) ###-####`  And remember that the fields are only 15 bytes wide and so the actual number must be less than13 characters (remember the elimination of the trailing newline and `fgets()` automatically appends a '\0' byte

Comment: Note: in America the `zipcode` is a combination of a 5byte number and a 4 byte number.  Which means that the `zip` field is way too short